# array<BYTE>^ to BYTE [] exact convert

Tags: c++-cli, clr

How to convert exactly:

```
array<BYTE>^ mntest = gcnew array<BYTE>{0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C};
to
BYTE unmtest [] = { 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C };
```

Resp. how to initialize unmanaged BYTE array to correct size of managed array.
Dynamic initialization of unmanaged array throws an error.

Comment: One byte at a time, there is no type conversion.  Consider whether you actually need BYTE[] and can't use BYTE*, pin_ptr<> is very efficient.  The code snippet is far too brief to make the call.

Comment: I didn't think this conversion is so complicated. I may have to rewrite some of the code.
This BYTE [] is the input parameter of the library function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found because dynamic initialization of static array is not allowed is conversion above possible only with using array pointer.